# Getting No module named osgeo

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, osgeo

I'm having this issue when I try to use the Polygonise(raster to vector) tool in QGIS 3.4.3 (Madeira) on a Mac running Mojave:

```
File "/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in <module>

from osgeo import gdal

ImportError: No module named osgeo
```

Some others have discussed this before and with reference to [QGIS 3.0 error when start in MacOS High Sierra](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276787), I note that I don't seem to have the
`/Python/3.6/site-packages`
sub-branch in my

```
/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3B/
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/
```

directories. I definitely have Python 3.6 (and not 3.7) installed.

To try to fix, I've reinstalled Python 3.6.8 using the installer from Python.org and I've reinstalled QGIS 3.4.3. Following these reinstalls, I still don't have the directory branches mentioned above and the Polygonise tool still doesn't work.

My presumption is that the lack of these branches is causing the problem (but I could be wrong).

What do I need to do to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncertain whether Python 2 or Python 3 is being used, try `python3`, then issue the command `import from osgeo import gdal`.

```
roblabs@27:~ $ python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import from osgeo import gdal
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> # No response, nor errors => good news
```

That just worked for me on macOS.  Your script that is calling the library `gdal_polygonize.py` is likely using macOS's installed version of Python 2, `python`.

You can also add `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` to the top of your `script.py` to explicitly use `python3`